# How do you pass user credentials to a WebLogic 11g Authentication Provider?

Tags: java, authentication, web-applications, weblogic, jaas

I think I've got a high level understanding of WebLogic's `AuthenticationProviders`, but I can't get my head around how to pass user credentials to a provider.

---

### My Understanding

When reading up on JAAS, I think I've got a grasp of how to use a `LoginContext` to perform a login. The `LoginContext` picks up on the `LoginModule` and JAAS options from the JAAS config file. By defining an instance of some `CallbackHandler`, you can pass along user credentials. After calling `LoginContext.login()`, the login is performed using the associated `LoginModule`.

After going through Oracle's documentation on `AuthorizationProviders`, most of it seems pretty straightforward. An `AuthenticationProvider` utilizes JAAS to perform a login. It seems like an `AuthenticationProvider` manages a `LoginContext` internally.

**What I'm having a hard time grasping/finding is how WebLogic manages the `LoginContext` and the `CallbackHandler` that eventually get passed to the `LoginModule.initialize` method.**

---

### The Situation

The app:

- Java web application running on WebLogic 11g (10.3.6).
- Attempting to authenticate with a username and password, **without** a form login.

Currently, the application uses a form login and submits with a "j_security_check" action. There's a custom `AuthenticationProvider` and `LoginModule` that handles the login and processes the username and password submitted in the form.

I'm assuming WebLogic can handle the "j_security_check" action internally and knows how to map the form input fields to a `CallbackHandler` that's passed to the custom `LoginModule`.

---

### My Goal

I'm attempting to create a second login process that involves extracting credentials (username/password) from  HTTP request headers. The credentials are currently extracted with a servlet filter. One way or another, I'd like to pass these credentials to the `LoginModule` that's already in place for the form login.

I would like to do one of the following:

1. Take the credentials straight from the headers and pass them to the `AuthenticationProvider` (through some custom `AuthenticationProvider` implementation and/or configuration)
2. Extract the header credentials with a servlet filter and manually pass them to the `AuthenticationProvider`.

---

### My Question

**What can I do to pass the header credentials to the `LoginModule`?**

1. Is there a predefined `AuthenticationProvider` that can pull a username and password from a header? Can you describe the flow from the request to the login?
2. Is there some way to get access to the `CallbackHandler` or `LoginContext` used by an `AuthenticationProvider`? This way I can pass the credentials to the `AuthenticationProvider` myself.
3. How does WebLogic know where to obtain user credentials and how to tie them to a particular `AuthenticationProvider`?

It's very possible I'm missing some key concepts along the way, so feel free to put me on the right track with anything I've mentioned.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to write your own authentication provider with your login module to achieve this. Start reading the [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13718/atn.htm#DEVSP205](documentation).  The trick to know is how to get the Http request object from your login module, to be able to read http headers filled with the login and the password. The http request object is available from the ContextHandler :  `Object requestValue = context.getValue("com.bea.contextelement.servlet.HttpServletRequest");`  
`HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) requestValue;`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out how I can get access to the request object. However, I'm still lost on where I should be accessing the request object. As far as I can tell, credentials passed to the `LoginModule` are passed through the `CallbackHandler`. I am unable to determine how to acquire the username/password from the request headers, then pass these to the `CallbackHandler` that is passed to the `LoginModule`'s `initialize` method. Am I incorrect in thinking I need to interact with this `CallbackHandler` before it gets passed to the `LoginModule`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My biggest hangup with understanding WebLogic's `AuthenticationProviders` was in understanding how to pass the credentials. It seemed like too many things were "automagically" happening behind-the-scenes. I felt like I had to somehow get access to a `LoginContext` and/or `CallbackHandler` that WebLogic manipulated in the background. I was on the right track, but missed something important about JAAS authentication...

[Authentication Providers - How JAAS Works With the WebLogic Security Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/web.1111/e13718/atn.htm#DEVSP214)

Steps 3 and 4 of a JAAS authentication are listed as:

> 3. The WebLogic Server container calls into the WebLogic Security Framework. **If there is a client-side CallbackHandler** containing
>      authentication information, **this is passed into the WebLogic Security
>      Framework**.
> 4. For each of the configured Authentication providers, the WebLogic Security Framework creates a CallbackHandler **using the authentication
>      information that was passed in**. (These are internal CallbackHandlers
>      created on the server-side by the WebLogic Security Framework, and are
>      not related to the client's CallbackHandler.)

This is the part that threw me off. My mind was tunneled in on a `CallbackHandler` passing WebLogic the authentication information. I failed to pick up on the note shown at the end of the steps:

> **Note**:
>
> For authentication performed entirely on the server-side, the process
>   would begin at step 3, and the WebLogic Server container would call
>   the weblogic.security.services.authentication.login method prior to
>   step 4.

[Authentication - Method Summary](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E68505_01/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/security/services/Authentication.html#method_summary)

And wouldn't you know it... `Authentication`has four `login` methods, each of which accepts a `CallbackHandler`!

For my situation, I can use the servlet filter to pick out the credentials from a request header, pass them to a `CallbackHandler`, then call `Authentication.login(CallbackHandler callbackHandler)` to successfully log in with a custom `LoginModule`.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old thread but I felt that it might be worth adding that a container agnostic option would be to call httpRequest.login(username,password) method.